# Remove an Openshift server from RHC

Tags: git, ssh, openshift, redhat, ssh-keys

I'm very confused about this rhc client. I always read about `cartridge` and `apps` on tutorials over the interwebs, but what I see when i try to setup rhc e a `server`.

I setup a server in this computer a few months ago. But I never used it. Now I created a new and personal account and I wanted to setup this computer to use rhc but my last setup is stuck there.

I tried to rund

```
rhc server remove <server-name>
```

but it says the server is already in use. Asks me to change servers. But I only got one. When I try to add a new server with the url `openshift.redhat.com` it says it is already setup. Of course.

What do I have to do to remove the current installation and install a new server in this computer? And what exactly is an app and a cartridge in Openshift context?

Is there a different way to upload stuff to OpenShift without configuring RHC?!

Answer (score 3):

Remove your ~/.openshift directory and then re-run rhc setup.  That will re-create the configuration file.