# RHC can't remove servers and hostname in SSH session

Tags: git, openshift

I can't connect with rhc ssh because a server is "bugging" my connection.

This server `broker.getupcloud.com` is overwriting `openshift.redhat.com`, but I removed `broker.getupcloud.com` server of the server-list.

I tried remove the path `~/.openshift` and re-run rhc setup, but was not effective.

I uninstalled GIT and all versions of RubyGems (for windows) and re-install the apps again. But also was not effective. The `broker.getupcloud.com` is blocking me to try connect with openshift server`.

Without erros, nothing. I just can't connect in ssh because of this problem.

See the image.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2iG2p.jpg

**---EDIT---**

**SOLUTION:**

> 1. Open regedit
> 2. Find for `broker.getupcloud.com`
> 3. Delete all register with this value
> 4. Re-run RHC Setup and be happy

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove an Openshift server from RHC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32021976/remove-an-openshift-server-from-rhc)

Comment: @mbaird I tried this solution.